# Return a use case response with a stream and a final result

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, stream

In dart/flutter, i try to determine a users GPS position once. Since a one-time query for a GPS position might be very inaccurate (accuracy ranges from 3 to 100m sometimes), i try to "listen" to the GPS location stream from the geolocator package over a certain time and pick the one with the highest accuracy.

This usually takes for example 20 seconds. After this, there is usually no notable improvement for accuracy anymore.

I wrote a use case which return a `DetermineGpsPositionResponse` with a `currentPositionStream`. This stream receives events, whenever the next incoming gps position is "more accurate" than the last one.

The frontend listens to this stream and display this "temporarly" position for feedback purpose.

But after the time of 20 seconds i wanna have the final result in the use case and close the stream from the use case side.

How is it possible to listen to the update stream temporarily, but let the listener also know, that the final result is now available and the application can move on?

I think it can be done somehow using streams and/or futures, but don't know how to do it in dart/flutter.

So, i guess i need still a `currentPositionStream` in my `DetermineGpsPositionResponse` but also a `finalPosition`value ... but how to manage the handover from the stream to the final result?

Comment: Instead of using raw location data in the stream, wrap it in class that has a property like `isProvisional`. As long as the value is `true`, you listen to the stream. Once the business logic determines it's good enough, the next value will be `false`, and you stop listening.

Comment: Or just use the [`onDone`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription/onDone.html) handler, and consider the last value received as the final one.

Comment: So you mean, just taking the stream as a result and not other values in the response?

Comment: The provisional flag seems to be a good one, but also closing the stream is a good idea ... i also want to make sure, there is no other "built-in" language feature exactly matching this kind of use case ... sometimes there are very handy language features :)